# Read List excel in R & then perform operation (two)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I already created a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67782861/read-list-excel-in-r-then-perform-operation), though now the task is to pick two entries from each column as output suggest

[image]

Sample dataframe

```
df <- structure(list(A = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4",NA), B = c("B1", "B2", 
"B3", "B4",NA), C = c("C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5"), D = c("D1", 
"D2",NA,NA,NA)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I apologize, but I didnt want to trim the output.

Comment: I wanted to clarify as you changed the output.  What if there are more than 5 rows

Comment: The output will continue to append if the rows in other columns are exhausted.

Comment: Looks good, is it possible to achieve what I posted in comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could reshape to 'long' format with `pivot_longer`, create a flag column based on the row sequence after grouping by 'name', then do the `arrange` on the 'flag' and the 'name' column, and remove the columns not needed

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), values_to = 'Output', 
        values_drop_na = TRUE)  %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(flag = row_number() > 2) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  arrange(flag, name) %>% 
  select(-name, -flag)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 15 x 1
   Output
   <chr> 
 1 A1    
 2 A2    
 3 B1    
 4 B2    
 5 C1    
 6 C2    
 7 D1    
 8 D2    
 9 A3    
10 A4    
11 B3    
12 B4    
13 C3    
14 C4    
15 C5
```

---

Or may also use `group_split`

```
library(purrr)
df %>%
    group_split(rn = row_number() > 2, .keep = FALSE) %>%
    map(~ .x %>%
         unlist %>% 
         na.omit) %>% 
    unlist %>% 
    tibble(output = .)
```

---

For the second case, we need a condition in the 'flag' creation

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), values_to = 'Output', 
        values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(flag = case_when(name == 'D' ~ row_number() > 1, 
        TRUE ~ row_number() > 2)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  arrange(flag, name) %>% 
  select(-name, -flag)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 15 x 1
   Output
   <chr> 
 1 A1    
 2 A2    
 3 B1    
 4 B2    
 5 C1    
 6 C2    
 7 D1    
 8 A3    
 9 A4    
10 B3    
11 B4    
12 C3    
13 C4    
14 C5    
15 D2
```

Comment: Thanks @Akrun, I have question what if I want to pick only one row from D column & rest 2 as above. Is there a way to accomplish that. The output would be A1,A2,B1,B2,C1,C2,D1,A3,A4,B3,B4,C3,C4,D2,C5

Comment: @VaibhavSingh Can you check the output nw

Answer (score 2):

we can use `split` and `unlist`:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% split(c(1,1,2,2,2)) %>%
        unlist()%>%
        keep(!is.na(.))

1.A1 1.A2 1.B1 1.B2 1.C1 1.C2 1.D1 1.D2 2.A1 2.A2 2.B1 2.B2 2.C1 2.C2 2.C3 
"A1" "A2" "B1" "B2" "C1" "C2" "D1" "D2" "A3" "A4" "B3" "B4" "C3" "C4" "C5"
```

Or simply

```
df %>% split(seq_len(nrow(.))>2) %>% unlist() %>% discard(is.na) %>% unname

 [1] "A1" "A2" "B1" "B2" "C1" "C2" "D1" "D2" "A3" "A4" "B3" "B4" "C3" "C4" "C5"
```

Answer (score 1):

This may works

```
df %>%
  mutate(E = is.na(.)%>% rowSums()) %>%
  melt(id.vars = "E")  %>%
  arrange(E) %>%
  na.omit %>% 
  select(value)

   value
1     A1
2     A2
3     B1
4     B2
5     C1
6     C2
7     D1
8     D2
9     A3
10    A4
11    B3
12    B4
13    C3
14    C4
19    C5
```

## Edit

```
dummy %>%
  mutate(E = is.na(.)%>% rowSums()) %>%
  melt(id.vars = "E")  %>%
  na.omit %>%
  arrange(E) %>%
  mutate(FF = max(E)) %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  mutate( E = ifelse(variable == "D" & !(value == first(value)), FF - 0.5, E)) %>%
  arrange(E) %>% select(value)

   variable value
   <fct>    <chr>
 1 A        A1   
 2 A        A2   
 3 B        B1   
 4 B        B2   
 5 C        C1   
 6 C        C2   
 7 D        D1   
 8 A        A3   
 9 A        A4   
10 B        B3   
11 B        B4   
12 C        C3   
13 C        C4   
14 D        D2   
15 C        C5
```

Comment: Thanks @Park, I have question what if I want to pick only one row from D column & rest 2 as above. Is there a way to accomplish that. The output would be A1,A2,B1,B2,C1,C2,D1,A3,A4,B3,B4,C3,C4,D2,C5

Comment: @VaibhavSingh Which one is you want? `D2 - C5` or `C5 - D2`

Comment: D2, C5 since that is logical completion of D & then C is pending. We in no case want to pick more than 2 rows if any other columns is left.

Comment: @VaibhavSingh I add another code above. It will work for another data too